# Why can't I use the BuildInDocumentProperties (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word) in a WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word

I have to change a Property in Word Documents and save them as PDF

(I Already installed the Nuget Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word)

In a console app it works perfect:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main ( string [] args )
        {
            var fileName = "TestDoc";

            Word.Application application = new Word.Application();
            application.Visible = false;
            var inputFileName = @"C:\Input\" + fileName + ".docx";
            var outputFileName = @"C:\Output" + fileName + x + ".pdf";
            Word.Document document = application.Documents.Open(inputFileName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: false);
            document.BuiltInDocumentProperties [ "KeyWords" ].Value = "Test Value";

            document.ExportAsFixedFormat ( outputFileName, Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF );

            // Close the document and the application
            document.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I do the same in my WPF Project

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

                        var fileName = "TestDoc";

            Word.Application application = new Word.Application();
            application.Visible = false;
            var inputFileName = @"C:\Input\" + fileName + ".docx";
            var outputFileName = @"C:\Output" + fileName + x + ".pdf";
            Word.Document document = application.Documents.Open(inputFileName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: false);
            document.BuiltInDocumentProperties [ "KeyWords" ].Value = "Test Value";

            document.ExportAsFixedFormat ( outputFileName, Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF );

            // Close the document and the application
            document.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error on the line `document.BuiltInDocumentProperties [ "KeyWords" ].Value = "Test Value";`

**Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'type'**

Is there a reason why this doesn't work in a WPF application or is there a way to fix this.

Comment: Did you use the same Framework for both applications? Here I still have an old Console project type that targets the old .NET Framework. When I use that, I do not see this error. When I start from the up-to-date .NET 7 Console template I see exactly the error you see. Beyond that, I don't know enough to help. You may need to make the question a bit more C#/.NET framework oriented. Word's BuiltInDocumentProperties has long been problematic - I think it's probably a "parameterized property", and it's entirely possible that .NET Core and later have "forgotten" how they work.

Comment: You are right, my wpf application is .net 7, an the console app .net feamework 4.8. I did not think about that. I will check if there is another library that works better for me. Thank you .